# Can't access all json properties

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json structure and for some reason I can't access the other properties. I can only "access" through the main properties like `type`, `properties` and so on with that hierarchy level. But I can't access to `icon`, `iconURL`, `title`. The data is there but I can access singularly.

If I use `console.log(markerRE[i].properties)`, it shows all the properties but if I want the title only, the console fires `can't read property properties of undefined`.

```
var markerRE = [{}]; //JSON ARRAY

$.ajax({
    url: 'consulta4.php',
    data: {},
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
            markerRE.push({
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "geometry": {
                        "type": "Point",
                        "coordinates": [data[i].longitude, data[i].latitude]
                    },

                    "properties": {
                        "title": "Emergencia: " + data[i].priority,
                        "id": data[i].id_emergency,
                        //"descripcion":"<button class='RE'>oisdjos</button>", Forma alternativa de añadir html
                        "icon": {
                            "iconUrl": data[i].imagen,
                            "iconSize": [50, 50], // size of the icon
                            "iconAnchor": [25, 50], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
                            "popupAnchor": [0, -25], // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
                            "className": "dot"
                        }
                    }
                }


            );
            console.log(markerRE[i].properties.title);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you iterating through `Object.keys` ?

Comment: im iterating it because i want to store all data from the ajax

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return properties of the object. You might need a for loop. Need to see `data`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try declaring markerRE as

```
var markerRE = []; //without {}
```

i tried in my own way bt not sure and I don know why but Using {} makes counter to be started from 1 not 0.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to me what you're doing above, as far as looping by the number of keys in your data. But I think one of your problems is also you are instantiating markerRE with an empty object already inside of it. Instead of just making it an empty array []. so  console.log(markerRE[0].properties.title); is going to be invalid because markerRE[0] is an empty object